# Usage of "Include Regions" in Jenkins

Tags: svn, url, jenkins

I am trying to use "include regions" in Jenkins.

Examples of svn URLS:

```
http://svn.mydomain.com/svn/projects/branches/Anudeep
```

`projects/branches/Anudeep/A1/A2/A3` is my work space which I have checked out from SVN.

```
"SVN URL: http://svn.mydomain.com/svn/projects/branches/Anudeep"
```

Build needs to be triggered only if there were changes in `A2` folder.

Please suggest some solution. I tried the "help" one in Jenkins. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use URL:

```
http://svn.mydomain.com/svn/projects/branches/Anudeep/A1/A2
```

Svn can do it.
And config SCM:
[image]
Look to crone syntax and config pull SCM.